# Erratic behaviour by Django application

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am running a Django application on my production server using apache and mod_wsgi. I have a test code that returns a simple HttpResponse. The problem is, sometimes I get the expected response and sometimes the page just keeps loading. Restarting the apache server seems to have no effect. Although, when I change the name of the url and the view function, it seems to start working fine again for sometime and then I start having the same problem again. I am not sure if there is some kind of caching being done on my server.

I found the following post which seems to mention a similar problem.

[django fails, sometimes, very erratic behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904505/django-fails-sometimes-very-erratic-behavior)

This problem has been troubling me for a very long time now and have not found a logical solution. Any help is appreciated.

P.S: In case its relevant: I am moving the code from my development machine to the production server using the SFTP integration from an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all `*.pyc` files on your server, then restart Apache.